# Convert 1-to-many relationship to lookup using linq

Tags: c#, linq, lookup

In my database I have an entry which has a 1-to-many relationship defined.

I just want a simple `Lookup` by the set relationship(s).

Simple example:

A car has values (like its manufacturer and type) in the same table and attributes (like color, hp, engine) which are defined in another table. (It's just an example which does not make sense from database point of view).

All I want is to select all cars from e.g. `Ford` as a lookup by their attributes but I dont get the point.

Currentyl I have

```
dbContext.Cars
    .Where(c => c.Manufacturer == "Ford")
    .Select(c => new {
        c.Type,
        Attributes = c.Attributes.Select(a => new{
            a.Value
        })
    })
    .ToLookup(arg => arg.Attributes.Select(a => a.Value), arg => arg.Type);
```

but this gives a weired lookup with the combined

I need a lookup like

```
[500hp] : {Type1,Type2}
[300hp] : {Type3,Type6}
[green] : {Type3,Type7}
[blue] : {Type2,Type1}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume what you need is the `SelectMany`:

```
dbContext.Cars
    .Where(c => c.Manufacturer == "Ford")
    .SelectMany(c => c.Attributes.Select(a =>new { c.Type, a.Value }))
    .ToLookup(arg => arg.Value, arg => arg.Type);
```

Comment: Many thanks. Indeed I was looking for a way to somehow flatten my results, but did not saw the simple solution. Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend to always look in the [SO Linq documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/68/linq-queries/346/flattening-a-sequence-of-sequences-using-selectmany#t=20161004091200612698) - this one is exactly about the flattening :) and there are many other good ones

Comment: Thanks for the link.